# Setting a default version of Python on Windows

Tags: python, windows

I am trying to run python on my pc but i dont know how to change default version

Console shows only 1 version but still uses 3.10, there are not even any files named Python310 in system so i dont understand how is it possible.

I tried changing system variables but still doesnt work.

Comment: setting the path order will allow you to dictate what version to use. I also recommend https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html